# Wordpress form shortcode based on form_id

Tags: php, wordpress

I am practicing with WordPress. I have created an simple form plugin which get form fields from database by form_id.
I am trying to add the form_id to the shortcode so if I enter shortcode with form id I will get the form based on the form_id.

I have this function for getting form fields and the I am looping through. The results are good So if I change manually the form_id I will get the results with same form_id.

**Code for getting form**

```
function my_html_form() {
    $results = my_form_get_form_id();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $form_id = $result->id;

        $fields = my_form_get_fields($form_id);
    }

    //in here I am looping through $fields and getting all fields
}
```

And In here I am adding the form to the shortcode I know this wrong to add the form_id like this but I dont know how.

**Adding shortcode**

```
function my_form_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    my_html_form();
    return ob_get_clean();
}


$results = my_form_get_form_id();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $form_id = $result->id;

    $fields = my_form_get_fields($form_id);
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $fields_form_id = $field->form_id;
        add_shortcode( "my_form_shortcode:$fields_form_id", 'my_html_form()' );
    }


}
```

So how can get the value for this `my_form_shortcode:$fields_form_id`. Right now I am just getting all form_id but the form just return the form with last id. So if type [my_form_shortcode:form_id]. I will get the form based on form_id.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add attributes to your shortcode function and call it using do_shortcode('[my_form_shortcode id=1]');

```
function my_form_function($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
                'id' => 0,
            ), $atts );
    ob_start();
    my_html_form($atts['id']);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( "my_form_shortcode", 'my_form_function' );
```

you can remove the id in my_html_form as it calls a function ( thinking it will generate the html )

**Edited**
I change the code above to fix some errors

as reference check link 
[Shortcode Atts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts)

Comment: Thanx for quick respons, So I will also need to add parameter form_id in my_html_form(). And how can I pas the form_id?

Comment: @user8124685 as stated about you can use it do_shortcode("[my_form_shortcode id=1]");. So If for example the form_id you want to show is 10 then all you need to do is do_shortcode("[my_form_shortcode id=10]");